# imageview not hiding on custom Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview

There is a custom listView where it displays the text or image or both. Now it is displaying the text or image or both but the problem is while only text display the space occupied for the imageView is still seen. I have set the Visibility to GONE also but it is not hide.

Adapter code for Listview:

```
public class DescAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

private final listdisplay ds;
private ArrayList<descusers> dusers;
private ArrayList<descusers> orig;

public DescAdapter(listdisplay ds, ArrayList<descusers> dusers) {
    this.ds = ds;
    this.dusers = dusers;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dusers.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dusers.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    descusers du = dusers.get(position);
    String username = du.loginname;
    String descCrip=du.descCrip;
    String Limage = du.image;

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ds).inflate(R.layout.customlist,null);
    TextView uname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    TextView desc = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

    ImageView iview= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageList);
    iview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    uname.setText(username);
    desc.setText(descCrip);

    if(!Limage.isEmpty()){
        Glide.with(convertView.getContext()).load(Limage)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).fitCenter().centerCrop().into(iview);
        iview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }


    return convertView;
}

}
```

Custom XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="226dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/test"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="username"
    android:textColor="#ff6aa9ff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Suggest"
    android:textColor="#ff06010b"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="165dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageList"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What wrong i have done in the above code?

**Answer:
    The problem is with the Linear Layout height which was set as android:layout_height="226dp" , Changed to Wrap-Content solved the problem.**

Comment: add `if(convertView==null){TextView uname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    TextView desc = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

    ImageView iview= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageList);
    iview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    uname.setText(username);
    desc.setText(descCrip);

    if(!Limage.isEmpty()){
        Glide.with(convertView.getContext()).load(Limage)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).fitCenter().centerCrop().into(iview);
        iview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }}`

Comment: Are you calling notifyDataSetChanged() after refresh your view?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya - Not worked, Same problem.

Comment: print this value above if statement and check what value is coming for each list item

Limage.isEmpty()

Comment: @MiguelBenitez - Yes, not included in above code.

Comment: @user2269164 please add `else` statement `else
        {
             convertView.getTag();
        }`

Comment: @RaghuNagaraju - Its empy when no image else url of image.

Comment: `if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ds).inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

try this code in getView method of Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    descusers du = dusers.get(position);
    String username = du.loginname;
    String descCrip=du.descCrip;
    String Limage = du.image;
   ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if(convertView==null){
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ds).inflate(R.layout.customlist,null);
    viewHolder.uname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    viewHolder.desc = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

    viewHolder.iview= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageList);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
}else{
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

    viewHolder.uname.setText(username);
    viewHolder.desc.setText(descCrip);

    if(!Limage.isEmpty()){
        Glide.with(convertView.getContext()).load(Limage)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).fitCenter().centerCrop().into( viewHolder.iview);
        viewHolder.iview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else{
      viewHolder.iview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    return convertView;
}
```

And Use this Class as Holder:

```
class ViewHolder {
    TextView uname;
    TextView desc;
    ImageView iview;


}
```

Comment: Already suggested by @IntelliJ Amiya in above comments check.

Comment: @jaydroider  have seen the code and tried it. whether its working or not?

Comment: In the above answer, imageview visibility won't work as expected. Since view is reused, you should always make the view visible or invisible/gone in the code based on the conditions.  


    'if(!Limage.isEmpty()){
        Glide.with(convertView.getContext()).load(Limage)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).fitCenter().centerCrop().into(iview);
        iview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else{
            iview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
'

Comment: @PradeepGupta - Still space is occupied for imageview even no image exists.

Comment: have you check that you are getting the Limage String have the value or not. because depend on the value of Limage String we had set visibilty.Or check the Empty String like  Limage.trim().isEmpty()